# What is a good CLI-based bitmap tracing method?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I often use the 'trace bitmap' function in Inkscape to create a vector image from a raster image. However, on larger or more complicated bitmaps, the program completely freezes. GUIs being what they are, I know that a command-line based approach would suit the task. So what's a good way to do that?

Comment: You may have a better chance for an answer on superuser?

Comment: Not an answer, but I can't imagine wanting to do such a visual task in a CLI...

Comment: @e100 It's a matter of clicking a tab and choosing a brightness cutoff. I'm not talking about tracing it using a tablet.

Comment: OK - I haven't used Inkscape to be honest, but in other apps tracing generally involves tweaking several factors interactively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The software that powers Inkscape's bitmap tracing function is actually a non-GUI program called Potrace, so you're in luck:

http://potrace.sourceforge.net/

Download here: http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading

Answer (score 1):

This one also supports centerline (for CAD)
https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace