# Command-line bitmap tracing with inkscape

Tags: inkscape, batch-processing, image-trace

Suppose you want to trace multiple bitmaps with some fixed inkscape tracing settings, is there a way to do it automatically with a batch file?

Comment: Related [one](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/483/18982) and [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17933944/2633637), but I actually would like to do it through inkscape, to have the tracing tool installed just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a repo for this task, too late but I hope it help

```
# New trace action with fully optional parameters
selection-trace:{scans},{is_smooth[false|true]},{is_stack[false|true]},{is_remove_background[false|true],{speckles},{smooth_corners},{optimize}}
# Example:
# Trace 256 colors then export to output.svg
$ inkscape.exe --actions="select-all;selection-trace:256,false,true,true,4,1.0,0.20;export-filename:output.svg;export-do;" "input.png" --batch-process
```

[link GitHub repository](https://github.com/nullmastermind/inkscape-for-trace/releases/tag/1.1.x)

If "true" or "false" doesn't work, replace it with "1" or "0".

Comment: Sure helped me, thanks :D

Comment: @bluevariant great work! are you planning to release a new version? the version you shared works in windows but I compiled in Linux and it doesn't work, it seems to be a problem fixed in 1.3.x

Comment: @utiq ty, I am currently studying more about C++ and will release a new version soon. I will remove the entire UI to make it able to run headless, but I think it will take a lot of time. No need to worry, my game company is using it and it is still guaranteed to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

### [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net)

Inkscape trace bitmaps with an embedded version of Potrace. Unfortunately we can not access this from the command line. In additions there are no shared libraries from Inkscape and Portrace meaning you will have to install potrace in addition to Inkscape for command line batch tracing of bitmaps.

The advantage of doing so is that you will have far more access to fine tune your traces with specific options nicely listed in the [potrace manual](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#usage).

On Linux systems potrace should be available from your software repositories. Source packages and precompiled binaries for other operating systems are [available from sourceforge](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading).

Comment: Potrace does only BW and grayscale images, inskape does the color ones too by separating the channels