# How do I get potrace commands out of inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, image-trace

I can get the `.pnm` ⇾ `.svg` results I want using the Trace Bitmap tool in the Inkscape GUI. If I understand it correctly, that tool is just a front end to Potrace. Is there a way to see what Inkscape is telling Potrace such that I can recreate the steps using the Potrace CLI? (I want to trace a bunch of `.pnm`'s, but it sounds like Inkscape's CLI can't do tracing)

I'm on a Mac which maybe cuts out the Potracegui solution.

The specific setup I have in Inkscape is:

- Multicolor
- Colors Detection mode
- 4 scans
- Smooth enabled
- Stack enabled
- Remove background enabled
- Speckles disable
- Smooth corners set to 1.00
- Optimize set to 0.200

Comment: See this related question: [Command line bitmap tracing with Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26275/command-line-bitmap-tracing-with-inkscape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billy's linked question was helpful, but unfortunately Potrace only does black and white tracing and I couldn't use the windows binary provided. Instead, I found [this](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic4d78.html?t=11898) post on the Inkscape forum that linked to [this](https://github.com/migvel/color_trace) github repo. I was eventually able to get it up and running with a few caveats:

1. You need a version of Python at least 3.2 to get color_trace to run, but it can't be past 3.7 since ["multiprocessing.Process itself is not picklable as of Python 3.7"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71945399/python-3-8-multiprocessing-typeerror-cannot-pickle-weakref-object). I eventually went with Python 3.6.15
2. Inkscape seemed to handle tracing transparent backgrounds okay, but color_trace won't AFAICT. I used `mogrify -background white -alpha remove -alpha off *.png` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background) to set all the backgrounds to white before tracing.
3. After that `python color_trace_multi.py -i source/*.png -d output/ -c 5 -s -bg` gave me pretty much what I had in Inkscape at scale.